# mysql nested query question

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to design a mysql query to retrieve the row for each city with the most recent trans_date and trans_count.  I only want to return a single row per city.

Table transactions

```
------------------
id = integer
trans_date = date
trans_city = varchar
trans_count = integer
```

Sample Data

```
--------------
id       trans_date     trans_city     trans_count
--       ----------     ----------     -----------
1        2011-01-10     seattle        2104
2        2011-04-15     seattle        2072
3        2011-05-30     seattle        2057
4        2010-04-27     houston        5622
5        2010-04-30     houston        241
6        2010-05-25     houston        261
```

Desired Query Results (one row per city with the most recent date and count for that city)

```
---------------------
id       trans_date     trans_city     trans_count
--       ----------     ----------     -----------
3        2011-05-30     seattle        2057
6        2010-05-25     houston        261
```

None of the samples I have found return this result set I'm looking for.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (
  SELECT id,trans_date,trans_city,trans_count 
  FROM transactions 
  ORDER BY trans_Date DESC) X 
GROUP BY trans_city
```

I can't add comments on the other answers but you need the nesting because otherwise the group by applies before the order by and doesn't give you the expected answer.

Comment: +1 @Bob, creative solution to fix the random picking of rows by the `group by` clause that MySQL allows for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, 
       trans_date, 
       trans_city, 
       trans_count 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY trans_city
ORDER BY trans_date DESC, trans_count;
```

Comment: The `group by` clause should come before the `order by` clause

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works on SQL Server, just for posterity's sake since the upvoted solution doesn't.

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    transactions AS t,
    (SELECT
        MAX(trans_date) AS max_date
    FROM
        transactions
    GROUP BY trans_city) AS subquery
WHERE
    subquery.max_date = t.trans_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `trans-city` 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY `trans_date` DESC, `trans_count` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with distinct_cities ( select max(id) as id, trans_city
from table
group by trans_city)

select t.id, t.trans_date, t.trans_city, t.trans_count
from table t join distinct_cities d on t.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

start with an inner pre-query for the last date per city.. then join based on that most recent entry per city

```
select t2.*
   from
      ( select t1.trans_city,
               max( t1.trans_date ) as MostRecentDate
           from 
               Transactions t1
           group by
               t1.trans_city ) PreQuery

      join Transactions t2
         on PreQuery.Trans_City = t2.Trans_City
         and PreQuery.MostRecentDate = t2.Trans_Date
```